# Copying array to constant memory from host memory

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have a cuda application where I am trying to copy from the host memory to constant memory. The copying is occurring without any errors. But I am not getting the values that needed to be copied and I am always getting 0 values in the constant memory when I am debugging the program. My code is something like this :

This variables are defined in a separate header.h file

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>


#define env_end 48
__constant__ float dev_h_top[2*env_end];
__constant__ float dev_h_bot[2*env_end];

__constant__ int dev_row_top[8];
__constant__ int dev_col_top[8];

__constant__ int dev_row_bot[8];
__constant__ int dev_col_bot[8];

void INIT_AG_PLACEMENT_FUNC(int *,int ,int ,int,double *,double *,int,int *,int *,int *, int *);
__global__ void AGENT_POSITION_FUNC(int *,double *,double *,int *,int *,int *,int *,int *,int *,double *, double *);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int i,j,t,k,test,iter;
    int *mat, *mat_ind_top,*mat_ind_bot;
    int rows,del_t,del_b;
    int *top_ag_prop,*bot_ag_prop;
    float init_p_val;
    double *p_top,*p_bot;
    double *top_tour_len,*bot_tour_len;
    float *h_mat_top,*h_mat_bot;       
    int row_top[8] = {1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1} ,col_top[8] = {-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1},row_bot[8] = {-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1},col_bot[8]={-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1};

    //GPU variables
    int *dev_mat,*dev_top_ag_ind_mat,*dev_bot_ag_ind_mat;
    int *dev_top_ag_prop,*dev_bot_ag_prop;
    int *dev_top_ag_srd,*dev_bot_ag_srd;
    double *dev_top_ag_prob, *dev_bot_ag_prob;
    double *dev_p_top,*dev_p_bot;
    //Random Variables
    curandState *state_t,*state_b;  

    cudaError_t status,error ;


    iter = 2;
    iter = 2; 
    rows = 16;                              
    del_t = 320;  
    del_b = 320;
    init_p_val = 200.0;

    //Main matrix
    mat = (int *)malloc(env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    memset(mat,0,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    mat_ind_top = (int *)malloc(env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    memset(mat_ind_top ,0,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    mat_ind_bot = (int *)malloc(env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    memset(mat_ind_bot,0,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));

    //Top and bottom phermone matrix
    p_top = (double *)malloc(env_end*env_end*sizeof(double));
    p_bot = (double*)malloc(env_end*env_end*sizeof(double));

    //Top agents properties matrix memory allocation & memset
    top_ag_prop = (int *)malloc(8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(int));
    memset(top_ag_prop,0,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(int));
    //Top agents tour length matrix allocation
    top_tour_len = (double *)malloc(((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(double));
    memset(top_tour_len,0,((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(double));

    //Bottom agents properties matrix memory allocation & memset
    bot_ag_prop = (int *)malloc(8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(int));
    memset(bot_ag_prop,0,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(int));
    //Bottom agents tour length matrix allocation and memset
    bot_tour_len = (double *)malloc(((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(double));
    memset(bot_tour_len,0,((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(double));

    INIT_AG_PLACEMENT_FUNC(mat, rows, del_t, del_b, p_top, p_bot, init_p_val,
        top_ag_prop, bot_ag_prop, mat_ind_top, mat_ind_bot);

    //Heuristics Matrix Memory allocation
    h_mat_top = (float *)malloc(2*env_end*sizeof(float));
    memset(h_mat_top,0,2*env_end*sizeof(float));
    h_mat_bot = (float *)malloc(2*env_end*sizeof(float));
    memset(h_mat_bot,0,2*env_end*sizeof(float));

    for (i=0;i<env_end;i++)  
    {   h_mat_top[i*2] = sqrt(double(((env_end-i)*(env_end-i)) +1));     // This stores the distance of the agents placed in the top
        h_mat_top[i*2+1] = (env_end-i);                                              // to the end of the environment target
        printf("%f\t%f\n",h_mat_top[i*2] ,h_mat_top[i*2+1] );

        h_mat_bot[i*2] = sqrt(double((i*i)+1)) ;                                     // This stores the distance of the agents placed in the bottom
        h_mat_bot[i*2+1] = double(i);                                                    // to the end of the environment target
    }


    //GPU and CPU both variables 
    //Device main matrix allocation and memory copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_mat,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mat,mat,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Device Top Agents index matrix variable memory allocation and copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_top_ag_ind_mat,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_top_ag_ind_mat,mat_ind_top,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Device Bottom Agents index matrix variable memory allocation and copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_bot_ag_ind_mat,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_bot_ag_ind_mat,mat_ind_bot,env_end*env_end*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Device top phermone matrix allocation and memory copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_p_top,env_end*env_end*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_p_top,p_top,env_end*env_end*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Device bottom phermone matrix allocation and memory copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_p_bot,env_end*env_end*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_p_bot,p_bot,env_end*env_end*sizeof(double),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Device Top agents properties memory allocation and memory contents copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_top_ag_prop,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_top_ag_prop,top_ag_prop,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Device Bottom agents properties memory allocation and memory contents copy
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_bot_ag_prop,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_bot_ag_prop,bot_ag_prop,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //GPU only variables
    //Device Top agents surrounding cells matrix memory allocation and memset    
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_top_ag_srd,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(dev_top_ag_srd,0,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(int));
    //Device Bottom agents surrounding cells matrix memory allocation and memset
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_bot_ag_srd,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(dev_bot_ag_srd,0,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(int));
    //Device Top agents probability matrix memory allocation and memset
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_top_ag_prob,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemset(dev_top_ag_prob,0,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(double));
    //Device Bottom agents probability matrix memory allocation and memset
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_bot_ag_prob,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(double));
    cudaMemset(dev_bot_ag_prob,0,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(double));
    //Device random number seed memory allocation for top and bottom agents
    cudaMalloc((void **)&state_t,8*((rows*env_end)-del_t)*sizeof(curandState));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&state_b,8*((rows*env_end)-del_b)*sizeof(curandState));

    status =  cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_h_top,h_mat_top,2*env_end*sizeof(float));

    if (status!=cudaSuccess)
    { printf("Error in allocating constant memory!!");
    }
    status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_h_bot,h_mat_bot,2*env_end*sizeof(float));//,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (status!=cudaSuccess)
    { printf("Error in allocating constant memory!!");
    }
    status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_row_top,row_top,8*sizeof(int));
    if (status!=cudaSuccess)
    { printf("Error in allocating constant memory!!");
    }
    status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_col_top,col_top,8*sizeof(int));
    if (status!=cudaSuccess)
    { printf("Error in allocating constant memory!!");
    }
    status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_row_bot,row_bot,8*sizeof(int));
    if (status!=cudaSuccess)
    { printf("Error in allocating constant memory!!");
    }
    status = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_col_bot,col_bot,8*sizeof(int));
    if (status!=cudaSuccess)
    { printf("Error in allocating constant memory!!");
    }
    //system("PAUSE");  

    dim3 gridDim_1(env_end/16,env_end/16,1);
    dim3 blockDim_1(16,16,1);

    AGENT_POSITION_FUNC<<<gridDim_1,blockDim_1>>>(dev_mat, dev_p_top, dev_p_bot, dev_top_ag_prop,dev_bot_ag_prop, dev_top_ag_srd, dev_bot_ag_srd,
                                                                                                      dev_top_ag_ind_mat, dev_bot_ag_ind_mat,dev_top_ag_prob, dev_bot_ag_prob);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    error = cudaGetLastError();
    if(error != cudaSuccess)
    {printf("CUDA Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
    }


    cudaFree(dev_mat);
    cudaFree(dev_top_ag_ind_mat);
    cudaFree(dev_bot_ag_ind_mat);
    cudaFree(dev_p_top);
    cudaFree(dev_p_bot);
    cudaFree(dev_top_ag_prop);
    cudaFree(dev_bot_ag_prop);
    cudaFree(dev_top_ag_srd);
    cudaFree(dev_bot_ag_srd);
    cudaFree(dev_top_ag_prob);
    cudaFree(dev_bot_ag_prob);
    cudaFree(state_t);
    cudaFree(state_b);

    free(top_ag_prop);
    free(bot_ag_prop);
    free(h_mat_top);
    free(h_mat_bot);
    free(top_tour_len);
    free(bot_tour_len);
    free(p_top);
    free(p_bot);
    free(mat_ind_top);
    free(mat_ind_bot);
    free(mat);
}


void INIT_AG_PLACEMENT_FUNC(int *mat,int rows,int del_t,int del_b,double *p_top,double *p_bot,int init_p_val,
    int *top_ag_prop,int *bot_ag_prop, int *mat_ind_top, int *mat_ind_bot)
{
    int i,j,t,k,t_r_rand,t_c_rand,b_r_rand,b_c_rand;

    for (i=0;i<rows;i++)
    {   for (j=0;j<env_end;j++)
    { mat[i*env_end+j]=1;
    }
    }

    for (i=env_end-rows;i<env_end;i++)
    {   for (j=0;j<env_end;j++)
    { mat[i*env_end+j]=2;
    }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<del_t;i++)
    {   t_r_rand = rand()%(rows +1);
    t_c_rand = rand()%env_end;
    if (mat[t_r_rand*env_end+t_c_rand]==0)
    { i=i-1;
    }
    else
    {   mat[t_r_rand*env_end+t_c_rand] = 0;
    }
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (i=0;i<del_b;i++)
    {   b_r_rand = rand()%(env_end-(env_end - rows))+(env_end - rows);
    b_c_rand = rand()%env_end;
    if (mat[b_r_rand*env_end+b_c_rand]==0)
    { i=i-1;
    }
    else
    {   mat[b_r_rand*env_end+b_c_rand] = 0;
    }
    }

    t=0,k=0;
    for (i=0;i<env_end;i++)
    {   for (j=0;j<env_end;j++)
        {   //id | index number | row | col | target col | future_row | future_col | empty cell 
            if (mat[i*env_end+j] == 1)
            {  top_ag_prop[t*8] = 1; top_ag_prop[t*8+1] = t; top_ag_prop[t*8+2] = i; top_ag_prop[t*8+3] = j;    
                top_ag_prop[t*8+4] = j; top_ag_prop[t*8+5] = -1; top_ag_prop[t*8+6] = -1; top_ag_prop[t*8+7] = -1;
                mat_ind_top[i*env_end+j] = t;
                t+=1;
            }
            else if (mat[i*env_end+j] == 2)
            {   bot_ag_prop[k*8] = 2;   bot_ag_prop[k*8+1] = k; bot_ag_prop[k*8+2] = i; bot_ag_prop[k*8+3] = j; 
                bot_ag_prop[k*8+4] = j; bot_ag_prop[k*8+5] = -1; bot_ag_prop[k*8+6] = -1; bot_ag_prop[k*8+7] = -1; 
                mat_ind_bot[i*env_end+j] = k;
                k+=1;
            }

            p_top[i*env_end+j] = init_p_val;
            p_bot[i*env_end+j] = init_p_val;
        }
    }

}

__global__ void AGENT_POSITION_FUNC(int *dev_mat,double *dev_p_top,double *dev_p_bot,int *dev_top_ag_prop, int *dev_bot_ag_prop, 
                                                                         int *dev_top_ag_srd, int *dev_bot_ag_srd,int *dev_top_ag_ind_mat, int *dev_bot_ag_ind_mat,
                                                                        double *dev_top_ag_prob, double *dev_bot_ag_prob)
{
    //Maximum using 20 automatic variables
    //7 registers are used, 13 left unused.
    int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x +threadIdx.x;

    if (col==0)
    { printf("%f\t%f\n",dev_h_top[row*2],dev_h_top[row*2+1]);
    }
    int index_loc;
    int ty = threadIdx.y, tx = threadIdx.x;
    int by = blockIdx.y, bx= blockIdx.x;

    __shared__ int mat_block_local[18][18];
    __shared__ int mat_ind_local_top[16][16];
    __shared__ int mat_ind_local_bot[16][16];
    __shared__ double p_mat_local_top[18][18];
    __shared__ double p_mat_local_bot[18][18];

    //Loading of Inner elements for the main and the indices matrices of top and bottom agents
    mat_block_local[ty +1][tx +1] = dev_mat[row*env_end+col];
    mat_ind_local_top[ty][tx] = dev_top_ag_ind_mat[row*env_end+col];
    mat_ind_local_bot[ty][tx] = dev_bot_ag_ind_mat[row*env_end+col];

    //loading of phermone matrix to the local shared memory
    p_mat_local_top[ty+1][tx+1] = dev_p_top[row*env_end+col];
    p_mat_local_bot[ty+1][tx+1] = dev_p_bot[row*env_end+col];

    if (ty<=1)
    { 
        //Left and Right Vertical Halo elements load (without corner elements)
        mat_block_local[tx+1][(blockDim.x+1)*ty] = ( ((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty)) >=env_end || ((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty)) <0)?-1:
            dev_mat[(by*blockDim.y+tx)*env_end+((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty))];

    p_mat_local_top[tx+1][(blockDim.x+1)*ty] = ( ((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty)) >=env_end || ((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty)) <0)?-1:
        dev_p_top[(by*blockDim.y+tx)*env_end+((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty))];

    p_mat_local_bot[tx+1][(blockDim.x+1)*ty] = ( ((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty)) >=env_end || ((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty)) <0)?-1:
        dev_p_bot[(by*blockDim.y+tx)*env_end+((bx+ty)*blockDim.x-(!ty))];

    //Top and Bottom Horizontal Halo elements load (without corner elements)

    mat_block_local[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][tx+1] = ( ( (by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty) ) >=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty))<0)?-1:
        dev_mat[((by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty))*env_end+ (bx*blockDim.x+tx)];

    p_mat_local_top[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][tx+1] = ( ( (by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty) ) >=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty))<0)?-1:
        dev_p_top[((by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty))*env_end+ (bx*blockDim.x+tx)];

    p_mat_local_bot[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][tx+1] = ( ( (by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty) ) >=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty))<0)?-1:
        dev_p_bot[((by+ty)*blockDim.y - !(ty))*env_end+ (bx*blockDim.x+tx)];

    //Corner halo elements load

    mat_block_local[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][0] = ((bx == 0) || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))<0 || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))>=env_end)?-1:
        dev_mat[((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))*env_end+(bx*blockDim.x-1)];

    p_mat_local_top[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][0] = ((bx== 0) || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))<0 || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))>=env_end)?-1:
        dev_p_top[((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))*env_end+(bx*blockDim.x-1)];

    p_mat_local_bot[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][0] = ((bx== 0) || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))<0 || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))>=env_end)?-1:
        dev_p_bot[((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))*env_end+(bx*blockDim.x-1)];


    mat_block_local[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][blockDim.x+1] = ( (bx+1)*blockDim.x>=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))>=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))<0)?-1:
        dev_mat[((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))*env_end+( (bx+1)*blockDim.x )];

    p_mat_local_top[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][blockDim.x+1] = ( (bx+1)*blockDim.x>=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))>=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))<0)?-1:
        dev_p_top[((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))*env_end+( (bx+1)*blockDim.x )];

    p_mat_local_top[(blockDim.y+1)*ty][blockDim.x+1] = ( (bx+1)*blockDim.x>=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))>=env_end || ((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))<0)?-1:
        dev_p_top[((by+ty)*blockDim.y-!(ty))*env_end+( (bx+1)*blockDim.x )];

    }                                                                                                         
    __syncthreads();


    if (mat_block_local[ty +1][tx+1] == 1)
    {
        index_loc =     mat_ind_local_top[ty][tx] ;//dev_top_ag_ind_mat[row*env_end+col];
        //Neighborhood store top
        dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)+1][(tx+1)-1];  dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+1] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)+1][tx+1];
        dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+2] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)+1][(tx+1)+1];  dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+3] = mat_block_local[ty+1][(tx+1)-1];
        dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+4] = mat_block_local[ty+1][(tx+1)+1]; dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+5] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)-1][(tx+1)-1];
        dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+6] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)-1][tx+1];  dev_top_ag_srd[index_loc*8+7] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)-1][(tx+1)+1];

        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)+1][(tx+1)-1]*(1/dev_h_top[(row+1)*2]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+1] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)+1][(tx+1)]*(1/dev_h_top[(row+1)*2+1]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+2] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)+1][(tx+1)+1]*(1/dev_h_top[(row+1)*2]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+3] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)][(tx+1)-1]*(1/dev_h_top[row*2]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+4] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)][(tx+1)+1]*(1/dev_h_top[row*2]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+5] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)-1][(tx+1)-1]*(1/dev_h_top[(row-1)*2]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+6] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)-1][(tx+1)]*(1/dev_h_top[(row-1)*2+1]);
        dev_top_ag_prob[index_loc*8+7] = p_mat_local_top[(ty+1)-1][(tx+1)+1]*(1/dev_h_top[(row-1)*2]);
    }
    else if (mat_block_local[ty +1][tx +1] == 2)
    {
        index_loc =     mat_ind_local_bot[ty][tx] ;//dev_bot_ag_ind_mat[row*env_end+col];
        //Neighborhood store bottom
        dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)-1][(tx+1)-1]; dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+1] = mat_block_local[(ty+1)-1][tx+1];
        dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+2] = mat_block_local[(threadIdx.y+1)-1][(threadIdx.x+1)+1]; dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+3] = mat_block_local[threadIdx.y+1][(threadIdx.x+1)-1];
        dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+4] = mat_block_local[threadIdx.y+1][(threadIdx.x+1)+1]; dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+5] = mat_block_local[(threadIdx.y+1)+1][(threadIdx.x+1)-1];
        dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+6] = mat_block_local[(threadIdx.y+1)+1][(threadIdx.x+1)]; dev_bot_ag_srd[index_loc*8+7] = mat_block_local[(threadIdx.y+1)+1][(threadIdx.x+1)+1];

        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)-1][(threadIdx.x+1)-1]*(1/dev_h_bot[(row-1)*2]);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+1] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)-1][(threadIdx.x+1)]*(1/dev_h_bot[(row-1)*2+1]);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+2] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)-1][(threadIdx.x+1)+1]*(1/dev_h_bot[(row-1)*2]);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+3] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)][(threadIdx.x+1)-1]*(1/dev_h_bot[row*2]);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+4] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)][(threadIdx.x+1)+1]*(1/dev_h_bot[row*2]);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+5] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)+1][(threadIdx.x+1)-1]*(1/dev_h_bot[(row+1)*2]);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+6] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)+1][(threadIdx.x+1)]*(1/dev_h_bot[(row+1)*2]+1);
        dev_bot_ag_prob[index_loc*8+7] = p_mat_local_bot[(threadIdx.y+1)+1][(threadIdx.x+1)+1]*(1/dev_h_bot[(row+1)*2]);
    }

    __syncthreads();
}
```

Now when I am debugging I am always getting 0 values in the dev_h_top,dev_h_bot as well as other constant variables. I don't know what wrong is happening. I know that proper values are getting stored in the host variables and there is no error indication in the copy function of the variable but I don't know why the desired values are not getting copied. I also wrote a dummy program which is running properly but I don't know what is wrong I am doing in this program. I am always getting infinity in the dev_top_ag_prob and dev_bot_ag_prob when I am doing a kernel debugging as the values in dev_h_top and dev_h_bot is 0. I am posting the dummy program which seems to be working perfectly and if this one runs correctly then my original program should. But unfortunately because of strange reasons it is not. The dummy program is as follows :

```
int main()
{
        int num,*test_var,test_cons_var[8]={1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1}, *test_res;
    int *dev_test,*dev_res_var;
    int i,j;

    num = 32;

    test_var = (int *)malloc(num*sizeof(int));
    test_res = (int *)malloc(8*num*sizeof(int));

    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {  test_var[i] = rand()%(10);
        printf("%d\n",test_var[i]);
    }

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_test,num*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_test,test_var,num*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_res_var,8*num*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(test,test_cons_var,8*sizeof(int));

    test_kernel<<<1,num>>>(dev_test,dev_res_var);
    cudaMemcpy(test_res,dev_res_var,8*num*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("\n\n");
    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {  for (j=0;j<8;j++)
        {printf("%d\t",test_res[i*8+j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    cudaFree(dev_test);
    cudaFree(dev_res_var);
    free(test_var);
    free(test_res);

    exit(0) 
}

__global__ void test_kernel(int *dev_test,int *dev_res_var)
{
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<8;i++)
    { dev_res_var[threadIdx.x*8+i]=dev_test[threadIdx.x]*test[i];
    }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Robert Crovella : I don't know what happened but all the comments and answers are gone. I just want to let you know I also made a dummy program exactly same as that you have suggested in your answer which is running perfectly well but the program I wrote is giving me this problem. That is why I don't know what to do.

Comment: I asked you to pose a new question, not edit your original question.  My answer and all the comments were no longer applicable to your new code and question, so I deleted them.  SO is intended to be a question and answer format, not a chat room. It's difficult for me to help you that way.  Furthermore, I did not ask you to dump a bunch of code into a question, I asked you to create a short, simple, compilable reproducer, that demonstrates the problem you are having and I can compile.  I don't want to have to wade through all your `scanf` lines.  I'm asking you to do a bit of work.

Comment: sure. I am sorry for the inconvenience you have to go through. I will make a new post with required compilable code and I will close this question. Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: Your code as you have posted does not compile for several reasons.  You haven't provided certain function definitions and also have some syntax errors.  When I worked around those, and added this line near the beginning of your kernel:  `if ((row==0)&&(col==0)) printf("dev_h_top[0] = %f\n", dev_h_top[0]);`  I got the following output: `dev_h_top[0] = 48.010414`.  This value matches the value I get if I print out `h_mat_top[0]` earlier in your code.  So I think `__constant__` is working fine for you and you have some issue trying to run the debugger.  Try some test `printf` statements.

Comment: You're not doing proper cuda error checking throughout your code, either.  I've mentioned this before to you so I'll dispense with the link to show you how.  Maybe your system is messed up, or the GPU is not working correctly.

Comment: I have done the exact same printf thing and I am getting a 0 value. How is this possible?

Comment: I don't know.  I'm not running *precisely* the code you have posted, because the code you have posted does not compile for me. (Try it yourself in a clean project space.  You won't be able to compile it either.)  So there may be a difference there.  Or your GPU may be messed up (bad install, some other issue).  Or your kernel may not be executing at all.  You're doing almost no cuda error checking.  How about doing all this legwork, and checking all these things?  I can't tell you exactly why.

Comment: I have added one more function which was missing and I hope you would be able to run the code without any errors just by copy and paste. In the meantime I would do my portion of detailed work as much as possible. Please let me know if the updated code doesn't compile. Thank you for you cooperation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I did error checking after my kernel launch using this code :
cudaThreadSynchronize();
     error = cudaGetLastError();
     if(error != cudaSuccess)
     {printf("CUDA Error: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error));
   }

My program executed without any error message.

Comment: Your code still doesn't compile for me.

Comment: It was my fault. I missed few things. I think it would this time. I have done more error checking and I got none. Please let me know if it doesn't this time again.

Comment: Why don't you also put in the 2 printf statements that I suggested, one that prints out `h_mat_top[0]` (after it is initialized) and one that prints out `dev_h_top[0]` in the kernel code.  Tell me what is printed out when you run it. Also get rid of all your `scanf` lines.  I don't know what to enter for those.  Just hard code some acceptable values.

Comment: I removed the scanfs. Now you don't have enter anything. It was my fault and I should have done it before. I already informed you that I did the printfs and it is giving me 0 as I am seeing in the debugging of the program. I just want to inform you about one more thing that I have written a dummy program which is running perfectly. It is small and I am posting it at the end of my original question.

Comment: Please actually enter the 2 printf statements that I requested in your code, so that when I copy and paste they will be there. Then I will take another look.

Comment: added the printfs as requested

Comment: Your code as posted still does not compile for me.  You also haven't told me what is the output you get from the 2 printf statements as I requested.  Also, your "dummy program" does not compile for me either.

Comment: Okay I am making sure that this time you won't get any compilation error in any of my code. I don't know why it is occurring and this time you won't get it. The 2 printfs that I am getting are as follows:   h_mat_top[0] = 48.010414 and dev_h_top[0] = 0.00000.

Comment: I don't think you were ever actually running the code you had posted in this question, since I've never been able to get it to compile as-is.  When I make a few small changes to the code you have posted here, I am able to compile and it prints out 48.010414 for both printf statements.  My guess is you are cutting and pasting pieces from the code you are actually running, which has some other issue, but the code you have posted in this question is mostly correct.  Probably when you actually run the code you post, you will discover this.

Comment: I really don't know what happened but I created a separate project and made a single cuda file where I was copying down the portions of codes. I was doing this to make sure that you don't get any error while compiling next time. But this time after compiling I saw that the two printfs matched and producing the same result. There is absolutely no change in the code. The only difference this time is I put everything in a single cuda file. This is really weird and I don't know what to say. Thank you so much for all your cooperation. I would get back to you if I face any further trouble.

Comment: I have edited the code in my original question and you would be able to run it without any errors or inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated, and you seemed to be confirming, the code you have posted here is not actually what you are running, and when you ran the code you have posted here, you got the correct result.

If you actually had your `__constant__` declarations in a different **module** that would be a problem.  As you have posted them in this question they are in the same module, since the header is included in the only module (.cu file) that is in this question.  But if your actual project has separate .cu files and you are putting `__constant__` declarations in one file but trying to use them in another, that is a problem.  `__constant__` declarations [have module scope only](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#qualifiers) unless you are using the device linker with separate compilation.  Since your constant declarations are in a header file, you might be getting into trouble this way.

Assuming you are not using separate compilation, make sure the `__constant__` declarations are only defined (included) in a single module (.cu file) and make sure that all modifications/updates/usage of them occur in that file only.

Comment: robert crovella:I was working more on my project and what I have noticed is not the constant declaration that creates the error. Now I am declaring the constant variables in a separate header file. But the host function and the kernel function which is using the constant variable needs to be on the same file. So we can declare the constant variables in a separate header file but the functions using it needs to be on the same file.